# Convert ALTO XML to formatted PDF/RTF/TXT?

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xml-parsing, file-conversion

I am looking to batch convert a large amount of ALTO format XML docs to various formats in Windows, txt at least, rtf if possible and pdf would be convenient as well.

[ALTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALTO_(XML)) is an xml standard used by libraries and archives to hold metadata/format/font/layout aware text for reconstruction in PDF images.

I have only the XML files for a large archive that I would like to convert for text mining. The software I am using requires clean text or rtf files, so converting the xml to plain text is kind of the goal. Because ALTO is a standard the conversion should be possible, no?

A bonus would be the ability to either embed the metadata in a pdf or convert it to a bibliographical format file like LaTex. This could be a separate program.

I'd appreciate any ideas,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get plain text from the ALTO xml, you may try implementing the simple method used in this (hacky) Python script in Java: https://github.com/cneud/alto-ocr-text.

I am not currently aware of a straight conversion to PDF or LaTeX though you may be able to do this with a stylesheet, based on how exactly your ALTO files look like.